# create and write data into file using OOP php

Tags: php, file

I am learning and new to object oriented programming in PHP5. I have good knowledge about PHP without OOP. So i need little help here in order to create new file and store my data into the file using OOP PHP. When i run this program it says 543 set written to CSV and its correct as it is coming from my readerfile which i will not mention here as it is big file and running properly. So i just need to store and check my data into file.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
namespace autodo\interfaces\writer;

/**
 *  Writes CSV Data to File
 */
class CSVFileWriter 
{
    public $filename="data.txt";
    private $filehandle;
    private $counter = 0;

    public function init() {
        // open/create file
        // maybe create tmp-File
        $file = fopen( $this->filename, "w" );
    }

    public function process($data) {

        $tmp = $data->getCSV();
        /*
        @todo open file, write data
        */
        fwrite( $this->file, "Data\n" );
        $this->counter++;
    }

    public function finish() {
        // close file   
        echo "\n".$this->counter." sets written to CSV\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework, you even already have the `$filename` and `$filehandle` variables. Have you tried to do something ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet please check the updated question what i am trying to do. As i said i am learning this things but making small mistakes..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am new to oop php5 i am trying to write my data into file but getting error as Undefined property fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$this->file` this way. In your init function, you directly used `$file` which is set only in the scope of your init() function.

So either you use your $filehandle variable (probably the best solution as this variable seems to exist for a reason), or you use $this->file everywhere in your code.

```
<?php
namespace autodo\interfaces\writer;

/**
 *  Writes CSV Data to File
 */
class CSVFileWriter 
{
    public $filename="data.txt";
    private $filehandle;
    private $counter = 0;

    public function init() {
        $this->filehandle = fopen( $this->filename, "w" );
    }

    public function process($data) {

        $tmp = $data->getCSV();
        fwrite( $this->filehandle, "$tmp\n" );
        $this->counter++;
    }

    public function finish() {
        fclose ($this->filehandle); 
        echo "\n".$this->counter." sets written to CSV\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting warning as Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given and also fire permission error as i checked the file permission are ok for the file in the given path

Comment: @ajay It means `fopen` didn't manage to open / create the file. Check this error on stackoverflow / google / PHP manual page of fopen, and you will easily find the possible problems and solutions for this error. (Most likely due to rights)

Comment: @ajay And it works ? If not, just do as I said : Read the PHP manual where you will find all the possible solutions. If you still can't get it to work, you might try to open a new question here on stackoverflow, but it is likely to get flagged as duplicate.

Comment: i am wondering i have given all the permission to the file but still getting this error ? Do u know may in the code we are doing something wrong ? i will also check the php manual now

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the `resource` from `fopen` into a local variable in your init method:

```
$file = fopen( $this->filename, "w" );
```

So later it is not available when you try to get it from your instance:

```
fwrite( $this->file, "Data\n" );
```

Change the line in your `init` method to store the `resource` in your instance property:

```
$this->file = fopen( $this->filename, "w" );
```

You should then also declare `$file` as class property.

Comment: i am getting warning as  Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given